# Django image url redirect is going through link for HTML template rather than media file?

Tags: html, django, url, redirect, django-templates

I have a Django app, a template on which contains an image. The problem I know is that the server is trying to display the image via the redirect link from the HTML template rather than from the media file.

Example:

```
<tbody>
{% for equipment in inventory_obj %}
    <tr>
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.id }}</td>  
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.name }}</td>  
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.total_quantity }}</td> 
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.location }}</td>
        <td class="table-blocks"><a href= "{{ equipment.img_reference }}">IMAGE</a></td>                                                        
        <td class="table-blocks">
            <a href="/EditInventory/{{ equipment.id }}" id="Edit-Page-Link">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor%}
```

BUT when I add `equipment.img_reference.url` - the app returns an attribute error saying that no file was found.

The `equipment.img_reference` also has a problem, when I click on the link, the app opens the image via the HTML app - url is:
`localhost/ViewInventory/images_uploaded/WIN_20210215_19_54_16_Pro.jpg` - when it should be this: `localhost/media/images_uploaded/WIN_20210215_19_54_16_Pro.jpg`

This is the `urls.py` file for the app and the project:

app:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views # . is from 'this app' import views

urlpatterns = [
     path("", views.homepage, name="home"), #name must be same as the function name in the views.py, the path('') in the urls.py of mysite looks for the same path in '' and then renders the page which follows that
     path("LossReport/", views.report_loss, name="loss_report_page"),
     path("AddInventory/", views.add_new_to_inventory, name="add_new_to_inventory"),
     path("AddPractical/", views.add_new_practical, name="add_new_practical"),
     path("EditPractical/", views.edit_practical, name="edit_practical"),
     path("ViewInventory/", views.view_inventory, name="view_inventory"),
     path("EditInventory/<int:id>", views.edit_inventory, name="edit_inventory"),
     path("Update/<int:id>", views.update, name="update"),
]
```

project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('inventory.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is the `settings.py` file where I have added the media root and media URL

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now if I am being honest, this was working perfectly fine until I started creating a new template. I have reversed all changes made to the application in hopes that this would work - but it doesn't :/

EDIT:

Here are the other files:

- views.py

```
def view_inventory(request):
    inventory_obj = Inventory_Equipment.objects.all()
    return render(request,"main/ViewInventory.html", {'inventory_obj': inventory_obj})
```

- models.py

```
class Inventory_Equipment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default="Name this Equipment") # might have to divide this into name from frop down and new name
    total_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) # qty to add an entirely new equipment - bottom of form
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Physics Office', blank=True)
    img_reference = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images_uploaded/')

    class Meta:
        db_table="inventory"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

- forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Inventory_Equipment

class Add_Inventory_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    new_quantity = forms.IntegerField(required = False, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    existing_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required = False)
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory_Equipment
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is the given error:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ViewInventory/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The 'img_reference' attribute has no file associated with it.

Currently it won't render this template because the template file has `{{equipment.img_reference.url}}` instead of `{{equipment.img_reference}}`.

Comment: Please include the `equipment` model and the full stacktrace of the error(s) your get

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in template :-

```
{% for equipment in inventory_obj %}
    <tr>
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.id }}</td>  
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.name }}</td>  
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.total_quantity }}</td> 
        <td class="table-blocks">{{ equipment.location }}</td>

    {% if equipment.img_reference %}

        <td class="table-blocks"><a href= "{{ equipment.img_reference }}">IMAGE</a></td>

    {% endif %}
                                            
        <td class="table-blocks">
            <a href="/EditInventory/{{ equipment.id }}" id="Edit-Page-Link">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: This doesn't work :/ Although the table is being rendered and there is no attribute error, the link still redirects to the the wrong URL.